# How to group a audit table by ticket reference and pull out name of team who made first entry per rerefence

Tags: filter, powerbi, aggregation, measure

I have a fact table with a list of audit entries to tickets. Each ticket has a reference such as INC123456 or SR123456.

I need to locate each reference and pull out first entry referring to that ticket reference.  Then pull out team who made the entry.  Now each ticket reference can have more than one audit entry and can apply to same team.  I do have start date and end date of each audit entry as well.

I want to find all tickets that originate from a particular team.

Then use this to filter data set.  Id like to do this **as  measure please**

Comment: Please add you sample data and expected output from them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

I've realised that this will not work for what I need. Due to fact that a ticket can be assigned directly to a team when it is logged by Service desk analyst.

So as such it would be hard to work out who the first team was without doing some lookup around person who logged the ticket. They might change jobs so that would not work.  Unfortunately our logging system does not record team at the same time